# Angularjs & php dynamic links

Tags: php, angularjs

```
<td><a ng-click="setRoute('forum')" href="#/forums?id=<?php echo $f_id;?>"><?php echo $f_name;?></a></td>


.when('/forums?id=:id', {
templateUrl: function(urlattr){
return 'app/components/forums/forums' + urlattr.id + '.php';
        }  
    });
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I want to have a dynamic link to **?id=** pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS routes don't work with query parameters. You need to use a more RESTful approach.

```
<td><a href="/forums/<?php echo $f_id;?>"><?php echo $f_name;?></a></td>


.when('/forums/:id', {
templateUrl: function(urlattr){
return 'app/components/forums/forums' + urlattr.id + '.php';
        }  
    });
```